# How to concatenate lists in python but keeping only either the last or first element of adjacent lists if the elements are equal

Tags: python

This seems like an easy thing to achieve but googling has left me with nothing useful.

I have say four lists like this: 
`[0,1,3], [3,5,6], [6,5,8], [9,1]`

I want to concatenate them but after concatenating, I just want, for example the only one `3` from concatenating 1st and 2nd lists, only one `6` from concatenating 2nd and 3rd but concatenating the 3rd and 4th should not remove any elements.

The output should be

`[0,1,3,5,6,5,8,9,1]`

I can not obviously concatenate the lists using the `+` and remove the duplicates or as some other elements might get removed. I have thought about some logic but it is not very "pythonic". Any way to do this easily?

Comment: The title doesn't match the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from functools import reduce

lists = [[0, 1, 3], [3, 5, 6], [6, 5, 8], [9, 1]]


def add(a, b):
    if a and b and a[-1] == b[0]:
        a = a[:-1]
    return a + b


combined = reduce(add, lists)
assert combined == [0, 1, 3, 5, 6, 5, 8, 9, 1]
```

Comment: beware of empty list cornercase though.

Comment: This is similar to what I had in mind. comparing the first and last and removing the first from `b`. It is more elegant using the `reduce`.  Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that there is a builtin method to help with this so you have to implement it yourself. Here's one way of doing it:

```
lists = [
    [0,1,3],
    [3,5,6],
    [6,5,8],
    [9,1]
]

output = []
for lst in lists:
    if not output:
        output.extend(lst)
        continue
    if output[-1] == lst[0]:
        output.extend(lst[1:])
        continue
    output.extend(lst)

print(output)
```